# Pandas get unique values in one column based off of another column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

Here I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Variable    Groups
1           [0-10]
1           [0-10]
2           [0-10]
2           [0-10]
3           [0-10]
3           [10-20]
4           [10-20]
4           [10-20]
5           [10-20]
5           [10-20]
```

I'd like to get only unique values for `Variable` column, but don't want to lose any duplicates that are in different `Groups`, so for example this:

```
Variable    Groups
1           [0-10]
2           [0-10]
3           [0-10]
3           [10-20]
4           [10-20]
5           [10-20]
```

Note there is still a duplicate 3 because there was one in each group. I've tried

`df_unique = df['Groups'].groupby(df['Variable']).unique().apply(pd.Series)`

but this is just returning a complete mess. Not sure what to do, help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html#) together with [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), as follows:

```
df.groupby('Variable')['Groups'].unique().explode().reset_index()
```

---

Another solution is to use [`GroupBy.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), as follows:

```
df.groupby(['Variable', 'Groups'], as_index=False).first()
```

**Result:**

```
   Variable   Groups
0         1   [0-10]
1         2   [0-10]
2         3   [0-10]
3         3  [10-20]
4         4  [10-20]
5         5  [10-20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
df.groupby(['variable',df['groups'].explode()]).head(1)
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.explode()` here.  No effect.

Comment: i believe you cannot groupby lists, so explode makes them object dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an expression that combines the two columns, and apply `unique` to the combination.